# Get jshint errors in a text file

Tags: javascript, jshint, static-code-analysis

I am using `jshint` for my code analysis. I run
 `jshint PATH_TO_.js` .
 Is there a way to print these errors into a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this from a terminal you can use the `>` character to output to file.

`jshint PATH_TO_.js > path/to/text/file.txt`

The above truncates the file prior to writing, if you want a continuous log file use `>>`

`jshint PATH_TO_.js >> path/to/text/file.txt`